# Problems in code to Print the possibilities of wins in a Coin game

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

**I am solving the below problem using backtracking recursion. The first code "CoinGame1" is providing correct solution but the second code "CoinGame2" is providing a wrong solution. I guess, there is something bad happening since i am reversing the string earlier before calling recursively.**

*Coin game: Alice and Bob are playing a game using a bunch of coins. The players pick several coins out of the bunch in turn. Each player can pick either 1 , 2 or 4 coins in each turn. Each time a player is allowed to pick coins,
the player that gets the last coin is the winner. It is known that at last, when 1 , 2 or 4 coins are left, the player with first turn will definitely pick 1, 2 or 4 coins as required and win. For example, if there are 2 coins in end and Alice is the first player to pick, she will definitely pick 2 coins and win. Given the number of coins and the order of players (which means the first and the second players to pick the coins), write a program to print all the possibilities of winner
of the game,

```
F(1, {alice,bob})
alice
F(6, {alice,bob})
alice, bob, bob, alice, bob, bob
F(4, {alice,bob})
alice
F(3, {alice,bob})
bob, bob*

                         f(6,{A,B})                                     
                     /                \               \
            f(5,{B,A})                 f(4,{B,A})      f(2,{B,A})
          /     |      \                   B wins         B wins
f(4,{A,B})  f(3,{A,B})  f(1,{A,B}) 
A wins     /    |    \       A wins        
          /     |     \
f(2,{B,A})  f(1,{B,A}) f(-1,{B,A})
B wins         B wins
```

**//SOLUTION1**

```
public class CoinGame1
{
   public static void Count(int n, String[] s)   // n: no. of coins 
                                               //s:{"Alice","Bob"} (order) 
  {
       if(n>0)
       {
           if(n==1 || n==2 || n==4) System.out.println( s[0] );  // if 1/2/4 
                                 //coins left, the one with first chance wins
           else
           { 
               Count(n-1,new String[]{s[1],s[0]});
               Count(n-2,new String[]{s[1],s[0]});
               Count(n-4,new String[]{s[1],s[0]});  
           }
       }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          String[] order = new String[]{"A","B"};
          Count(6,order);
      }
}
```

> java CoinGame1
>   A
>   B
>   B
>   A
>   B
>   B

**//SOLUTION2**

```
public class CoinGame2
{
   public static void Count(int n, String[] s)          // n: no. of coins    
                                                 //s:{"Alice","Bob"} (order) 
  {
       if(n>0)
       {
           if(n==1 || n==2 || n==4) System.out.println( s[0] );  // if 1/2/4 
                                //coins left, the one with first chance wins
           else
           {
               String temp = s[0]; s[0] = s[1]; s[1] = temp;     // reverse s
               Count(n-1,s);
               Count(n-2,s);
               Count(n-4,s);  
           }
       }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          String[] order = new String[]{"A","B"};
          Count(6,order);
      }
}
```

> java CoinGame2
>   A
>   B
>   B
>   B
>   B
>   B

Comment: In your second snippet, you're mutating the array, but this same array instance is used across all iterations. Put `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s));` before each `Count(...)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1225328.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks ....The second code is only giving 4th value incorrect..i am unable to understand by debugging. I tried to debug the second code and foundout that f(-1,{B,A}) is returning to f(5,{B,A})  (instead of f(5,{A,B}) ) which eventually calls f(1,{B,A})) (instead of f(1,{A,B}) ) returning B . Why is f(-1,{B,A}) not returning to f(5,{A,B})?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to simplify recursive problems sometimes. I re-wrote your problem, but I made it start with 5 coins and a choice of 1 or 2. This way, the first picker will always win. The only way you can lose is to pick twice in a row, and the results speak for themselves. Run this code and the conclusion is clear, as mentioned above, the same instance of s is being run through out the entire process.

```
    public static void Count(int n, String[] s)          // n: no. of coins
    //s:{"Alice","Bob"} (order)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
            if(n==1 || n==2 ) System.out.println( s[0] );  // if 1/2/4
                //coins left, the one with first chance wins
            else
            {
                String temp = s[0]; s[0] = s[1]; s[1] = temp;     // reverse s
                Count(n-1,s);
                Count(n-2,s);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] order = new String[]{"A","B"};
        Count(5,order);
    }
    // the result is B,B,B,A,A
```

Comment: In this case, the correct answer should be B, B, A, A, A . The code should return B, B, A, A, A. The same problem we are facing in this code also. same instance of Array 's' is running also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in SOLUTION2 (this now gives correct result)

```
import java.util.*;
    public class CoinGame2
    {
       public static void Count(int n, String[] s)          // n: no. of coins    ,  s:{"Alice","Bob"} (order) 
      {
           if(n>0)
           {
               if(n==1 || n==2 || n==4) System.out.println( s[0] );  // if 1/2/4 coins left, the one with first chance wins
               else
               {
                  // String temp = s[0]; s[0] = s[1]; s[1] = temp;     // reverse s

                   String[] t = Arrays.copyOfRange(s,0,s.length);
                   String temp = t[0]; t[0] = t[1]; t[1] = temp; 

                   Count(n-1,t);

                   Count(n-2,t);

                   Count(n-4,t);  
               }
           }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args)
          {
              String[] order = new String[]{"A","B"};
              Count(6,order);
          }
    }
```